# How to fetch all products in the cart after place order button in my custom module

Tags: magento2, cart, custom

Step 1: I want to fetch all products in the cart and Show them with a form individually

Currently, I am fetching data using this code

```
<?php
namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Block;

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// retrieve quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
```

And this is my prescription.phtml code, it shows me empty page in the frontend

```
<h1><?php echo $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems(); ?></h1>
```

Step 2: How to display that page after placing an order (Before onepage/success)?

Actually I am new to Magento

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to show current Order Item on that page, right?

Comment: Yes I want to show current order items

Comment: Did you get the Current Order in your block file?

Comment: No I did not get

Comment: I update answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get Order in this way :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$sessionObj = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage'); 
$session = $sessionObj->getCheckout();
$order = $session->getLastRealOrder();
```

Now from the `$order` you need to get there items.

```
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($orderItems as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
```

**NOTE:** do not use $objectManager, instade of that one include proper class in constructor and then use there object in standard magento way.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it in steps?

Comment: I update answer, please check.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to place this page after checkout (Place Order Button) and before order success page?

Answer (score 1):

> Try below

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $obj->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getLastRealOrder();


$itemsVisible = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
$items = $order->getAllItems();
//other order data
$orderId=$order->getEntityId();
$incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

**You should not use the ObjectManager directly!**

Comment: Now how to display it in phtml file